# Variable defined in a function is not usable in another function which calls the first

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following and got an error message that "x is not defined".

```
def test():
    x = 2
    y = 3
    return x

def main():
    test()
    print(2 + x)

main()
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: because you didn't defined `x` in your second function!

Comment: `x` was assigned as a local variable in `test`, which means nothing to `main`.

Comment: Add `global x, y` as the first line in `test`

Comment: There's a function called `locals()` that's real useful to looking around which local variables you have, and a matching function known as `globals()`. Don't actually use these in production code, but they're useful for "uh, what do I have in scope?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is defined in `test`, but not in `main`

This means that `x` is not defined in `main`'s *scope*

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) for more details regarding scope. Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1555990).

If you want to use the value assigned to `x` in `test`, you need to assign the return value of test to a name:

```
def main():
    value_of_x_from_test = test() # This is the same as `x = 2` in `test`.
    print(2 + value_of_x_from_test)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `x` again, and the way to do that is say `x = test()`. The `x` from `test` only exists in `x`, which is why you need to reassign it.

It doesn't even have to be x, it could be `y`, or `z`: `x` is simply the name you *return*, the value you use in `main()` can be called anything!

Or, you can just call the function directly in `main()`, in which case you won't even need the first line in the main function:

```
def test():
    x = 2
    y = 3
    return x

def main():
    x = test() 
    print(2 + x) #or just `print(2 + test())`

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because of scope.  X is defined in test, but not in main().  Try setting x = test() in main, and everything should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of x is defined locally in test(), it cannot be used by main. Instead you can use directly the output of test as it is shown in the following code:

```
def main():
    print(2 + test())
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?

Comment: @Zulu now is edited!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of `x` in `main()`, you have to assign it to something:

```
def main():
    value = test() # The variable can be 'value' or any other valid name, including 'x'
    print(2 + value)
```